# What causes the rainbows with beautiful forms by shining white light on a cd?

Tags: optics, refraction, interference

When you shine white light on the mirror side of a cd you see beautiful coherent rainbow forms. What causes these forms? When trying to find out by searching the net, it didn't become very clear to me. It was said it's the same phenomenon as the strangely noncoherent deformed rainbows you see if you shine white light on an oily surface on top of water. The thickness of the oil layer varies slightly over the surface which causes light of different frequencies to interfere constructively or destructively. But the layer on the cd doesn't vary in thickness, and the patterns you see are very coherent, in contrast to the rainbow patterns you see on an oil layer. So what's causing these beautiful coherent rainbow patterns?

So I don't ask why these patterns occur for white light which have small phase related regions, but why the effect itself appears (by diffraction gratings I read below), but how, and why have the rainbow patterns beautifully coherent forms, which change shape if you look at different angles.

Comment: As far as I know, the grooves on the CD form a diffraction grating with a slit spacing narrow enough to observably affect different wavelengths of light differently.

Comment: The CD acts as a diffraction grating.  See [Is that a result of thin film interference?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128409/) and [Why does a CD act as a diffraction grating?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82061/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a CD work as a diffraction grating even with light from a light bulb?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/82061/)